# Найти экземпляр карты на странице по клику на объект верстки и получить массив всех объектов найденной карты

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

У меня есть кнопка все карты, никак не связанная по инициализации с картой (div class="class-name" Button, к примеру) и где то на странице инициализирована карта. Как мне по клику найти эту карту и получить массив объектов этой карты?

Comment: Почему вы решили что нужно действовать именно так? Какой конечный результат вы хотите видеть? Я к примеру при отрисовке точек на карте записывал их в js массив а потом можно прикрутить событие клика на вашу кнопку чтобы работать с этими данными. Вы смотрели примеры из [песочницы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1), может они вас на мысль наведут?

Comment: Допустим у меня есть что то вроде легенды, она по функционалу не привязана к карте. Теперь нужно по клике на определенный блок, фильтровать объекты на карте